# Paramiko not recognised by Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, paramiko, linux-mint

I have to use a script written in Python 3 which requires `paramiko`.

I installed `paramiko` by doing:

```
pip install paramiko
```

and got:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): paramiko in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages Requirement already satisfied (use
--upgrade to upgrade): pycrypto>=2.1,!=2.4 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from paramiko) Cleaning up...
```

I tried executing `import paramiko` for Python and Python 3 and it did not work for Python 3, as given below:

**Python:**

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import paramiko
>>>
```

**Python 3:**

```
Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import paramiko
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'paramiko'
>>>
```

How can I make `paramiko` visible to Python 3?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you can see from the path pip shows:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/
```

You have `paramiko` isntalled in Python 2.7 and *not* 3.

Use `pip3`(python installer for 3.x version) with `pip3 install paramiko` (using `sudo` if necessary) or `python3 -m pip install paramiko` to get the version of `pip` which installs to the directory for Python 3.

Comment: `sudo pip3 install paramiko` did it

Comment: Ah, yes, `sudo`ing is in some cases.

Answer (score 3):

check if pip3 is installed

```
which pip3
```

then

```
 pip3 install paramiko
```

if that doesn't work, download the package and unzip it.

```
  python3 setup.py install
```

and that'll work for sure.

Plus, if you're running a fun distro of linux with a package manager, you can dnf/yum/zyppr/apt-get install python3-paramiko

Answer (score 0):

First, you are using pip and not pip3 tries to install pip3 (sudo apt install python3-pip) and run the command pip3 install paramiko
If the error continues to, verify the version of ubuntu. If the version is 16, it uses python3 version 3.5.2 (paramiko don't work in this version), so I recommend upgrading to 18 because python3 version is 3.6.8 and paramiko will be installed successfully.

Answer (score -1):

```
$ sudo -H pip3 install paramiko --ignore-installed
```